# black box function export in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, export, black-box

Is it possible to export a function in MATLAB in such a way that it is possible to execute that function, but do not read its source code?

I would like to distribute a MATLAB application to the students while keeping a functionality as a black-box. So they can execute a program and see the results. Then, they should re-implement that black-box functionality, without being able to read the solution from the distributed application.

Comment: Yes you can generate a pcode which can't be read: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html